# How to load navigation child items from a controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Am having issues loading navigation(child ) element from a controller to a view

I created this model

```
public class MultipleItems
{
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<support> Supports { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DbModel.Track> Tracks { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Quota> Quotas { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller

```
public ActionResult Client()
{
    string useremail  = User.Identity.GetUserName();
    var  myModel = new MultipleItems();
    myModel.Supports = new SupportW().GetSupports(useremail);
    myModel.Orders = new Orders().GetOrders(useremail);
    myModel.Receipts = new Receipts().GetReceipts(useremail);
    myModel.Tracks = new Track().GetTracks(useremail);
    myModel.Quotas = new Quotas().GetQuota(useremail);
    return View(myModel);
}
```

Am interested in `Tracks()` and this is the method

```
public IEnumerable<DbModel.Track> GetTracks(string email)
{
    try
    {
        using (var da = new CourierEntities())
        {
            da.Tracks.Include(a => a.Order);
            da.Tracks.Include(a => a.Order.User);
            da.Tracks.Include(a => a.destination);
            da.Tracks.Include(a => a.Source);
            da.Tracks.Include(a => a.CurrentLocation);
            var q = (from p in da.Tracks where p.Order.User.Email == email select  p).ToList();
            if (q != null)
            {
                return q;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        returnMsg = ex.Message;
        return null;
    }
}
```

While the view is

```
<td>
    @if (Model.Orders.Count() != 0)
    {
        foreach (var i in Model.Tracks)
        {
            <tr>
            Order id      @i.OrderID
            <br />    
            Trackid    @i.TrackID
            <br />  
            @i.Order.Packagename 
            </tr>
        }  
    }
</td>
```

> am having issues with  @i.Order.Packagename   and i recieve this error
>
> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for 
>   operations that require a connection.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
>   current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext
>   instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for
>   operations that require a connection.
>
> ```
> Source Error:  
> Line 120:
> Line 121:                                          <br />  
> Line 122:                                          @i.Order.Packagename 
> Line 123:                                      </tr>
> ```

Comment: Read [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)

Comment: It seems that you need to use view model concept. Search google for mvc use view model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the comments suggest the use of a View Model, which would be a good idea, the fundamental issue with your code is the lifetime of the database context(s).

When you execute code such as:

```
myModel.Supports = new SupportW().GetSupports(useremail);
```

The object `SupportW` has a lifetime of that statement. It will likely be disposed before your view executes. If the method `GetSupports(useremail)` returns `IQueryable` then when that is resolved in the view, the source is no longer there.

To resolve this you should change the lines to:

```
myModel.Supports = new SupportW().GetSupports(useremail).ToList();
```

The addition of the `ToList()` resolves the `IQueryable' immediately and the data will be available in your view.

Comment: Thank, for the break down